# Getting a div's content all on one line - display: Inline block not behaving like expected

Tags: html, css

I’m a beginner web developer, currently practicing by putting together a simple website. In my header I want to have my main title sandwiched between two identical images, all on one line. For some reason setting their shared div's display property to inline-block isn't achieving this like usual, while providing a more specific selector to just the h2 does. I've commented out the style that is working.

```css
#siteName {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* #siteName h2 {
  display: inline-block;
} */
```

```html
<div id="siteName">
  <img src="./images/PurplePalace.png" alt="A Purple Floating Castle">
  <h2 class="heading"><a href="">The Purple Pizza Palace</a></h2>
  <img src="./images/PurplePalace.png" alt="A Purple Floating Castle">
</div>
```

Any insight into what the difference is here and why it is happening would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if I'm just missing something simple, I want to understand the situation, but have been unable to find an explanation.

Comment: Seems to be working fine, what were you expecting?

Comment: I've edited the code to comment out the style that is working. I mainly want to understand why my top style isn't putting everything on one line.

Comment: Because headings are display block by default and so 100% wide. Inline-block is not inherited.

Comment: Try changing the display to flex.

Comment: Thanks. That was definitely the detail I was missing. I appreciate the help.